# What is a database mission-statement?

Tags: mariadb, erd, architecture

What exactly is a **database mission-statement**?  My question was prompted after submitting an academic-assignment requiring a "mission-statement" for ERD-modeling.  I've yet to encounter this requirement out in the wild as a software engineer, and I presume a mission-statement is akin to a thesis-statement, but I remain unsure after my Google-search.  Any DBA professional example or guidance explaining the ideal "database mission-statement" would be appreciated- thanks!

Comment: It's not a memo...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought that Jeffrey Yao did a fantastic job answering this question [here.](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/jeffrey_yao/2009/01/03/dba-mission-and-vision-statement/) I've edited it a little bit and sometimes include my own mission statement on my resume, but here's my "slightly" modified version of Jeffrey Yao. This is not specific to mariadb, but I don't think it has to be.

> "Mission: I am committed to providing a robust and secure database
>   system for my customers and as such, I proactively maintain and
>   monitor the database system to prevent any potential issues;
>   accurately diagnose and forecast the database system health and
>   capacity; quickly respond to support request(s) and persistently seek
>   innovative ways to improve DBA work efficiency and quality."

Comment: Nice find, and thank you for your clarification.  I also discovered this [Quora-post](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-a-mission-statement-important-in-database-planning) a few moments ago, which appears to support your answer in cooperation with Mr. Jones- thank you!

Comment: So honored to see my blog being referenced here, thank you,  @Shaulinator.